# Wifi network stopped being visible (and usable) (Linksys wag320n)

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

Basically, my wifi network simply stopped working for no apparent reason. It doesn't appear in the list of the available networks anymore. I can see all my neighbors' networks, but not mine. It's as if it doesn't exist anymore. The internet connection (non-wifi), which goes through the same modem/router, is fine though.

I already had a similar problem about one year ago (see here: [Wifi network SSID not visible](https://superuser.com/questions/334293/wifi-network-ssid-not-visible/) ), just after buying this very modem. I finally got it to work after performing two factory resets and getting rid of the Cisco "Magic" software; but this time it's not working.

I use a linksys router-modem (WAG320N) which is directly connected (via network cable) to my desktop computer (Windows 7). I have (mainly) two devices that use the wifi network: my phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) and an Asus tablet (TF201, aka Transformer Prime). I also resurrected an old laptop computer (Dell, running Windows XP) to test that, and it doesn't see anything either (apart from the 20 other wifi networks, of course ^^).

This wifi network was working just fine and has been for about a year. I haven't touched the modem settings so I have no idea what's causing the problem.

I tried:

- making my phone "forget" about my network, hoping it would see it again after that: no luck.
- re-entering the network informations (SSID/password) manually on my phone: still no luck (says it's not in range)
- exporting the modem configuration, resetting the modem (factory reset, via modem admin), restarting it, importing the configuration: nope.
- factory reset, turning it off for 15 minutes, restarting, re-factory reset, and entering the configuration manually: still nothing.

Has anybody experienced something similar before?
Have you any suggestion to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

PS: to clear things up, here are the settings of my modem regarding wifi:

**Basic wireless settings:**

Configuration: manual
Radio Band: 2.4GHz Wireless
Network Mode: B/G/N-Mixed
SSID: s427
Channel Bandwidth: Wide - 40 MHz Channel
Wide Channel: 9 - 2.452GHz
Standard Channel: 11 - 2.462GHz
SSID Broadcast: Enable

**Advanced Wireless Settings**

AP Isolation: Disable
Authentication Type: Auto
Basic Rate: Default
Transmission Rate: Auto
N Transmission Rate: Auto
CTS Protection Mode: Disable

Beacon Interval: 100
DTIM Interval: 1
Fragmentation Threshold: 2346
RTS Threshold: 2346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeking advice on the linksys ( http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Cable-and-DSL/Linksys-WAG320N-Wifi-network-stopped-being-visible-and-usable/m-p/579254 ), it appears the problem is probably a hardware one.
No solution found, I'm buying a new modem.